# want to calculate the count of pass instances of data set using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```html
x=[]
y1=[]
r1=len(df)
L1=len(df.columns)

for i in range(r1):
    ll=(df.loc[i,'LL'])
    ul=(df.loc[i,'UL'])
    count1 =0
    for j in range(5,L1):
        if isinstance(df.iloc[i,j],str):
            df.loc[i,j]=0
        
        if ll<=df.iloc[i,j]<=ul:
            count1=count1+1
    if count1==(L1-5):
        x.append('Pass')
    else:
        x.append('Fail')
    y1.append(count1)  
    
se = pd.Series(x)
se1=pd.Series(y1)
df['Min']=min1.values
df['Mean']=mean1.values
df['Median']=median1.values
df['Max']=max1.values
df['Pass Count']=se1.values

df['Result']=se.values

min1 = df.iloc[:,5:].min(axis=1)

mean1=df.iloc[:,5:].astype(float).mean(axis=1,skipna = True)
median1=df.iloc[:,5:].astype(float).median(axis=1,skipna = True)

max1=df.iloc[:,5:].max(axis=1)
count1=df.iloc[:,5:].count(axis=1)


yield1=[]
for i in range(len(se1)):
    yd1=(se1[i]/(L1-3))*100
    yield1.append(yd1)
    
se2=pd.Series(yield1)  
df['Yield']=se2.values
df1=df.loc[:,['PARAMETER','Min','Mean','Median','Max','Result','Pass Count','Yield']]
df1
```

Below is my data set, it is sensor data on daily basis. Daily data should be within the Lower Limit (LL) and Upper Limit(UL). I want to count how many days sensors data is within the LL and UL.
I am not able to calculate the number of days for sensor data within LL and UL using Pandas. How can I calculate the number of days for sensor data within LL and UL?
[image]

Comment: provide your data as text not an image

Comment: sensor location,LL,UL,day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7,number of days sensor data within LL and UL
A,1,10,12,6,9,4,9,7,15,5
B,1,12,4,15,7,1,11,1,7,6
C,1,15,13,13,13,10,7,13,13,7
D,1,10,12,1,14,12,15,4,4,3
E,1,20,11,15,8,14,1,14,14,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a few key ideas

1. need a list of the columns that go into calc `daycols`
2. transpose these columns into an array then to test, gives a boolean array
3. sum this boolean array and you have your desired calc

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""sensor location,LL,UL,day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7,number of days sensor data within LL and UL 
A,1,10,12,6,9,4,9,7,15,5 
B,1,12,4,15,7,1,11,1,7,6 
C,1,15,13,13,13,10,7,13,13,7 
D,1,10,12,1,14,12,15,4,4,3 
E,1,20,11,15,8,14,1,14,14,7"""))

daycols = [d for i,d in enumerate(df.columns) if "day" in d and "number" not in d]
df = df.assign(
    # use fact true is 1 so sum a truth array gives the answer
    daysBetween=lambda dfa: ((dfa.loc[:,daycols].T>=dfa["LL"]) & 
                             (dfa.loc[:,daycols].T<=dfa["UL"])).sum()
)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
sensor location  LL  UL  day1  day2  day3  day4  day5  day6  day7  number of days sensor data within LL and UL   daysBetween
              A   1  10    12     6     9     4     9     7    15                                             5            5
              B   1  12     4    15     7     1    11     1     7                                             6            6
              C   1  15    13    13    13    10     7    13    13                                             7            7
              D   1  10    12     1    14    12    15     4     4                                             3            3
              E   1  20    11    15     8    14     1    14    14                                             7            7
```

#### speed up

It you have many columns then you can use slice capability to identify them and turn into indexes so `iloc` can be used.  Additionally the transpose is not necessary.

```
dayi = [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in df.columns[3:-1]]
df = df.assign(
    # use fact true is 1 so sum a truth array gives the answer
    daysBetween=lambda dfa: ((dfa.iloc[:,dayi]>=dfa["LL"]) & 
                             (dfa.iloc[:,dayi]<=dfa["UL"])).sum()
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Rob Raymod, it is very useful to me

Comment: thank you for help , in real case scenario , i will have lot of columns(say 1000) and columns names will be different (sometimes data set will have dates).so i want to access all columns from column3 to (last column-1). i want to use iloc function for this as below but this code not working and taking very long time to execute on large data

Comment: please refer to original post added the code , below part in the above code is not working                                                                                       for i in range(r1):
    ll=(df.loc[i,'LL'])
    ul=(df.loc[i,'UL'])
    count1 =0
    for j in range(5,L1):
        if isinstance(df.iloc[i,j],str):
            df.loc[i,j]=0
        
        if ll<=df.iloc[i,j]<=ul:
            count1=count1+1
    if count1==(L1-5):
        x.append('Pass')
    else:
        x.append('Fail')
    y1.append(count1)

Comment: I provided a vector based solution and you have changed it back into a looping solution.  so it will perform very badly.   I could have `daycols = df.columns[3:-1]` used this instead.  Point is you need a list of columns that need to be compared to UL & LL

Comment: I've updated so it matches what you are saying you want thousands of columns...